# Excel Macro- Not able to run a .exe file

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to run an application and even though the app is running it is not showing the desired results. But when I simply double-click the application it runs properly.

```
RetVal = Shell("D:\Automation Analyzer\Issue Type\dist\PatternDetectorAppv6.0.exe", 1)
```

The error that is coming on a popup after running this app via the above code is given below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PatternDetectorAppv6.0.py", line 18, in <module>
File "configparser.py", line 959, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'FILE_PATH'
[19428] Failed to execute script PatternDetectorAppv6.0
```

Comment: What is the result you get, how is it different from the result you expect? Did you change the working directory?

Comment: The error that is coming on running this app via the above code is given below.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PatternDetectorAppv6.0.py", line 18, in <module>
File "configparser.py", line 959, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'FILE_PATH'
[19428] Failed to execute script PatternDetectorAppv6.0

Comment: So, did you change the working directory?

Comment: No
How to do that?

Comment: Google, or even Stackoverflow seach box, will probably point you to  [ChDir("D:\Automation Analyzer\Issue Type\dist\")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/chdir-statement) and [ChDrive("D:")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/chdrive-statement)